# Помогите с алгоритмом калькулятора, для нахождения квадратного корня, возведения числа в квадрат и в куб

Tags: алгоритм, delphi-7, калькулятор

```
implementation

{$R *.dfm}
// sqr
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
If (Edit1.Text <> '')  then
Edit2.Text := Sqr(FloatToStr(StrToFloat(Edit1.Text)) ;
end;
// sqrt
procedure TForm1.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
If (Edit1.Text <> '') then
Edit2.Text := Sqrt(FloatToStr(StrToFloat(Edit1.Text));
end;
// x^3
procedure TForm1.btn3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
If (Edit1.Text <> '') then
Edit2.Text := FloatToStr(StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
end;


end.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sqr(FloatToStr(StrToFloat(Edit1.Text)) ;
```

То есть сперва число конвертируется из строки в число, а потом тут же из числа в строку, еще до вычисления квадрата? А квадрат уже считается от строки? В самой внешней комозиции порядок аргументов перепутан, мне кажется.кажется.

И еще закрывающей скобки не хватает.

```
Edit2.Text := FloatToStr(Sqr(StrToFloat(Edit1.Text)));
```

Так?